# How to re-enumerate kdb database

Tags: kdb

I have a database with a bloated sym file (350million+) due to id columns being symbols.
This is a large database, 1TB+ with 5 years of data.
I can use dbmaint to convert the string columns to symbols. But how do I re-enumerate the database so I can have a new sym file that doesn't contain those symbols from the id columns?

Comment: This article may help https://code.kx.com/q/kb/compacting-hdb-sym/

Comment: Here's additional information https://code.kx.com/q/wp/symfiles/

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment in case [the article](https://code.kx.com/q/kb/compacting-hdb-sym/) is ever lost or moved.

It gives the following code that can be used on a hdb to clean up the sym file. If your sym file has a different name then the code will need modified to include that. This assumes you have a simple hdb with:

- date partitions
- a single sym list
- only splayed tables

Note the warning before you start:

> This is an all-or-nothing approach. Run the code below at your own risk.
> Ensure you understand what it does, and test it against a dev HDB you are happy to destroy in the event of an error.

```
/cd hdb
/q
system "mv sym zym";
`:sym set `symbol$(); / create a new empty sym file
files:key `:.;
dates:files where files like "????.??.??";
{[d]
  root:":",string d;
  tableNames:string key `$root;
  tableRoot:root,/:"/",/:tableNames;
  files:raze {`$x,/:"/",/:string key `$x}each tableRoot;
  files:files where not files like "*#";
  types:type each get each files;
  enumeratedFiles:files where types within 20 76h;
  / if we have more than one enum better get help
  if[any types within 21 76h;'"too difficult"];  
  {
      `sym set get `:zym;
      s:get x;
      a:attr s;
      s:value s;
      `sym set get `:sym;
      s:a#.Q.en[`:.;([]s:s)]`s;
      x set s;
      -1 "re-enumerated ", string x;
  }each enumeratedFiles;
 }each dates
```

It may be possible to backup enumerated columns only beforehand in case you need to recover, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.

A good point noted in the article:

> This process is not a fix for a poor choice of schema!

But it sounds like you have addressed schema issues.